# Change depth of bookmarks for appendix

Tags: bookmarks, appendix

I already achieved to increase the depth of TOC to subsubsection for the appendix.
Now I want to change the bookmark depth the same way. The TOC and PDF bookmarks should have the same structure. Maybe someone has a solution for this. Thanks in advance!

And if anyone has a more elegant way to get the subsubsections in appendix numbered, let me know :)

Here is the current output:

[image: Appendix subsubsection is missing in appendix]

Small example:

```
\documentclass[
a4paper,
10pt,
numbers=noenddot,
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{footnotebackref}

\hypersetup{
    bookmarksnumbered,
    bookmarksdepth=2,
    bookmarksopenlevel=1,
    bookmarksopen=true,
}

\appto\appendix{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}}}
\appto\appendix{\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}}
\appto\appendix{\renewcommand*{\thesubsubsection}{\Alph{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

% Main part of document with depth down to subsection
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}

\appendix

% Appendix with depth down to subsubsection
\chapter{Appendix}
\section{Appendix Section} 
\subsection{Appendix Subsection}
\subsubsection{Appendix Subsubsection}

\end{document}
```

Comment: simply remove the `bookmarksdepth=2,` (or reset it before the appendix)

Comment: Didn't know that hypersetup can be called mid document. Thank you!
So `\appto\appendix{\hypersetup{bookmarksdepth=3}}` was the solution for me.